# connection error in using url connection and outputstream in android

Tags: android

Facing Problem to get the specified url connection. Here is my code.
its giving IOexecption when i try to connect through servlet its giving error in Communication Error Please Check Mobile/WI-FI Connection.

package com.solution.tamba.hrms;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
//import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.channels.Channel;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.al.amf.events.ErrorEvent;
import com.al.amf.events.ResultEvent;
import com.al.amf.remoting.RemoteListener;

public class HRMSS extends Activity implements Channel, RemoteListener, LocationListener {
    Button button;
    EditText companyId, userName, password;
    TextView t1;
    double plong;
    double plat;
    public static String email;
    public static int empNo;
    public static String empName;
    public static String emp;
    public static int emNo;
    LocationListener ll;
    LocationManager lm;
    public static String serverUrl = "http://192.168.2.233:8080/echo";
    CheckBox cb;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final String PREFS_USER = "username";
    String username;
    boolean isGPS;
    SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hrms);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        //  pref=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
//        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // companyId=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
        cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbUserName);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        ll = new MyLocationListener();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);


        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 1.0f, this);
        isGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


        addListenerOnButton(R.layout.activity_hrms, savedInstanceState, savedInstanceState);


//          
        pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = pref.getString(PREFS_USER, null);

        userName.setText(username);

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                username = userName.getText().toString();//get user name from EditText

                getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(PREFS_USER, username).commit();
//                    t1.setText();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();

        lm.removeUpdates(ll);

    }


    private void addListenerOnButton(int activityHrms, Object Private, Object Public) {


        final Context context = this;
        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (username.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    username.setError("UserName is required!");
                } else if (password.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    password.setError("Password is required!");
                } else if (checkInternetConnection() == false) {

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            HRMSS.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Connection Error");

                    alertDialog.setMessage("Please enable network connections");

                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)        

              startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);

                        }

                    });

                    alertDialog.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.cancel();

                        }

                    });

                    alertDialog.show();


                } else if (isGPS == false) {

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            HRMSS.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS");

                    alertDialog.setMessage("Please enable GPS setting and restart the Application");

                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);

                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.cancel();

                        }

                    });

                    alertDialog.show();
               } else {
                   Context c1 = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text1 = "Please Wait...";
                    int duration1 = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(context, text1, duration1);
                    t1.show();
                    String st = "a";
                    try {
                        String charset = "UTF-8";
                        URL urlServlet = new URL(serverUrl);
                        URLConnection con = urlServlet.openConnection();

                        st = st + ",ab";
                        con.setReadTimeout(30000);
                        con.setDoInput(true);
                        st = st + ",ab1";
                        Map<String, Object> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Object>());
                        con.setDoOutput(true);
                        st = st + ",ab2";
                        con.setUseCaches(false);
                        st = st + ",ab3";
                        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-java-serialized-object");
                        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
//                      con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
                        st = st + ",ab4";

                        OutputStream outstream = con.getOutputStream();
                        st = st + ",ab51";
                        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstream);
                        st = st + ",ab52";
                        map.put("id", "1");
                        map.put("username", username.getText().toString());
                        map.put("password", password.getText().toString());
                        map.put("lat", plat);
                        map.put("lon", plong);
                        map.put("state", "login");

                        oos.writeObject(map);

                        st = st + ",ab6";
                        InputStream instr = con.getInputStream();
                        st = st + ",ab7";
                        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
                        st = st + ",ab8";
                        Map<String, Object> map1 = Collections.synchronizedMap((Map<String, Object>) inputFromServlet.readObject());
                        st = st + ",ab9";
                        if (Integer.parseInt(map1.get("result").toString()) == 1) {
                            email = map1.get("userName").toString();
                            empNo = Integer.parseInt((String) map1.get("empNo"));
                            empName = map1.get("empName").toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HrmsOption1.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                            Context context = getApplicationContext();
                            CharSequence text = "Welcome To HRMS";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            toast.show();

                        } else {
                            Context context = getApplicationContext();
                            CharSequence sequence = "Invalid Credentials";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, sequence, duration);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                        st = st + ",ab10";

                        TextView username1;
                        //username1.setText(((String)map1.get("result"))+((String)map1.get("value")));

                        st = st + ",ab11";
                        instr.close();
                        st = st + ",ab111";
                        inputFromServlet.close();
                        st = st + ",ab112";
                        outstream.flush();
                        st = st + ",ab113";

                        oos.close();
                        st = st + ",ab114";
                        outstream.close();

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        //username.setText(st+e.toString()+"1");
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Communication Error Please Check Mobile/WI-FI Connection1";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //username.setText(st+e.toString()+"2");
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Communication Error Please Check Mobile/WI-FI Connection2";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        //username.setText(st+e.toString()+"3");
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Communication Error Please Check              Mobile/WI-FI Connection3";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
//              Intent intent=new Intent(context,HrmsOption.class);
//              startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
}
     private void removeLoginDetails() {
        Editor e = pref.edit();
        e.putBoolean("rememberMe", false);
        e.remove("login");
        e.remove("password");
        e.commit();
    }
      private void saveLoginDetails() {
        String loginbtn = userName.getText().toString();
        Editor e = pref.edit();
        e.putBoolean("rememberMe", true);
        e.putString("login", loginbtn);
        e.commit();
    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hrms, menu);
        return true;
}
  public void onError(ErrorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
   public void onResult(ResultEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
      public boolean isOpen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
     private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Internet Connection Not Present");
            return false;
        }
    }
     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            plong = location.getLongitude();
            plat = location.getLatitude();`
}
     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                    Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Be specific. Nobody is going to read all the code. Only post the code where you are getting the error.

Comment: check your internet connection,then try it.